# jQuery not working for me?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I've been starting to learn a little about jQuery. I know *very* little about  JavaScript. I've made my own little JavaScript using jQuery in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErraticFox/95ge3bwu/). For some reason though, I cannot get it to work outside of JSFiddle. I first tried implementing it on my website, didn't work. Then I made some local files (index.html, style.css, test.js), I put them all in the same folder and linked them all in index.html. I have to be missing something, but I do not see what it is.

Here are the contents of the files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="buttons"> 
            <a href="#" id="register">Register</a>
            <a href="#" id="login">Login</a>
        </div>
        <div id="prompt">
            Username
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <br/>
            Password
            <input type="text" name="password" />
            <br /> 
            <span class="fakelink">Go back</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
#prompt { 
     display:none;
}
```

**test.js**

```
        $("a#login").click(function () {
        $("div#buttons").slideToggle();
        $("div#prompt").slideToggle();
    });

    $(".fakelink").click(function () {
        $("div#buttons").slideToggle();
        $("div#prompt").slideToggle();
    });
```

Comment: The script is loading before the DOM is ready. Wrap your jQUery code in an on read function: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Or include your jQuery at the end of the document. See http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/. The reason it works in the fiddle is because fiddles default to loading the code you enter on the window's load event.

Comment: I highly recommend to read the [**jQuery tutorial**](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/#launching-code-on-document-ready)

Comment: @FelixKling - I've seen this, but I misinterpreted Document Ready. I thought that meant it would execute the code automatically. i.e. it would automatically do slideToggle without any clicking.

Comment: Nope. There even is an example for binding events: *"For example, inside the ready event, you can add a click handler to the link: ..."*.